# Java printing a rectangle of stars based on this code

Tags: java

a program that takes two command line arguments, n and m, and prints
a square/rectangle of stars n-by-m (n rows and m columns). how would i achieve this loop so that if i had typed in the numbers on command line (5 5) then it would print a square thats 5 lines of stars?

```
public class Looper {
    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        for(int i = 0;i < args.length;++i){
            for(int j = 0;j < Integer.parseInt(args[i]);++j)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend attempting to solve this problem yourself, and asking or searching for any specific questions that come up in the process. Stack solving this for you ain't gonna help you learn to code.

Comment: Split your task in small steps like (1) taking values from user (2) using values to print rectangle. For now skip part 1 and focus on part 2 but instead of user input use some predefined variables like `int n = 4, m = 5;`. Try to work with these `n` and `m`. When you will have working code simply add code which will put in `n` and `m` values from user (you seem to know how to do this).

Answer (score 4):

is this what you are looking for?

```
public static void main (final String[] args)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt (args[0]); ++i)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt (args[1]); ++j)
         {
            System.out.print ("* ");
         }
         System.out.println ("");
      }
   }
```

Comment: yeah thank you, i had been trying for ages, how does this work?

Answer (score 4):

In your commande line write :

```
java yourProgramsName 5 5
```

And call the first value of `args` in the first loop and the second in the second loop

```
public class Looper {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i = 0;i < Integer.parseInt(args[0]);++i){
            for(int j = 0;j < Integer.parseInt(args[1]);++j){
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I find your inconsistent curly bracket formatting odd.